# How to start .sh file on PC turn on or after PC restart?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, ssh

I have a `.sh` file in my `Downloads` directory. I want to start it using `tmux` session when computer is turn on or after computer is restarted.

I am using Ubuntu `12.04.4` and when the computer is turned on the user is not logged in automatically - a password is required. Also, the guest account is disabled.

In my `/home/user/.bashrc` file I have added the following lines:

```
/etc/init.d/ssh start
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

in order when the PC is restarted to be able to instantiate `SSH` session if the user is not logged in.

What I need is to find a way to start the `.sh` file, too but using `tmux` session.

Could anyone point to me the steps of doing such thing?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use [cron](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) for this. Look under special characters for `@reboot` keyword.

Run your command inside new tmux session (put this into cron):

`/usr/bin/tmux new-session "/bin/bash /path/to/script"`

Comment: Thanks, I have installed `cron` and setup a job, but it is not executed after restart. If I execute the line in the console it is working, but is not executed automatically on restart. Could you advice? This is the line: `@reboot sleep 300 && cd "/home/gotqn/Downloads/folder1" && /usr/bin/tmux new-session -s miner 'sh ./runnow.sh'`

Comment: With cron you have to use full path. Also make sure all of the needed programs are installed (sleep, sh, tmux...). Try `@reboot /bin/sleep 300 && /usr/bin/tmux new-session -s miner '/bin/sh /home/gotqn/Downloads/folder1/runnow.sh'`

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in /etc/init/myappname.conf with:

```
author "YourName"
description "Start myappname at boot time"
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE!=lo)
script
su myusername -c "tmux new-session -d 'myAppExecutablePath'"
end script
```

Directly copied from [this link](https://bowerstudios.com/node/953), but to make the answer complete.
For extra information on the start stop options [see this link](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

Comment: Thanks, but the job is still not started. I try to start the job manually running `sudo initctl start myjob` and I get the following message `myjob start/running, process 3100` but my script is not executed. Again, if i executed the script manually in the console it is working.

Comment: Still if it says process running the init script looks to be ran. Maybe the script relies on environment variables which are not available in the new shell? Maybe you can check by simply making a very easy debug notice within the init conf just to check it is being executed?

Comment: I guess you are right because I have try different ways to execute it on reboot and no one works. How can  I make such notice?

Comment: Lot's of options for that, have the upstart script make a testfile somewhere, parse some debug messages from your script to a testfile or replace your script all together with an example script which will show you the setup works.

Comment: You could also have a look at: http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html